# Loading user control dynamically in two directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, css

I am developing a commenting like platform where user can post comments and other users can reply on that comments. But these comments can be replied in two directions (Reply & Expand). The idea is that user can reply and user can also expand that discussion. Please see image.

[image]

I have developed a control which will be added dynamically whenever user will Reply or Expand a comment.

If user will reply on control a new control will be added under that message (comments) and if user Expand that message (comments) then a control with expanded reply (message) will be added on right side of that messages (comments). More than one user can Expand a message and users can also reply on expanded message.

I am not sure that what should be the place holder or container in which these control should be added.

- Should I use Server `Table` control and create `TableRows` and `TableCells`
  dynamically?
- What container should I use so page don't get too heavy?
- Should I create `divs` and adjust its position on runtime and add control in each
  `div`?

Other question on which I am not clear are:

- More than one user can expand a message, in this case how to handle
  UI. Hide/Show controls or any other solution.
- Should I show horizontal `scrollbar` on Expansions or is there other
  solutions?

Any help/suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I would strong suggest you use <div>s and CSS for the dynamic controls. These <div>s can be positioned relative to your main control.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in different ways, i am not going to give you code cause i want you to try and learn. So you can do all this with JQuery, you don't need Asp.net controllers, cause sometimes they are complicated to work with.

**So 1º step:**
You can create a simple table with 2 Columns and `N` rows depending on the number of messages you have (try filter some, Example: you have 100, show only 10 and have a "next page") or use some plugin table that hold bigdata for you.

**2º Step:**
when you reply a message create an `<tr>` in you table to place the "reply of first message" (note: you need to create a structure to handle you navigation on the table easily with `ID's`)

**3º Step:**
in your second column have like a `<div>` prepared to receive and show the expand message when user click "expand" and clean it always when a new message is expanded.

That should work for you, there are others ways but try to think in something simple

**Other Questions:**

1º - I didn't understand the question, but if your site will run on a server, user1 and user2, ... userN use the same page but render in different places, you just need to reload data to let everyone known that someone comment or reply or whatever in a message.

2º - UI its your choice, see what is best for you ;)

enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed answer Ricardo. Let me try this and I will get back to you, if needed.

Comment: Ricardo, do you understand that each message can be expanded. If a user expanded root message (first message) then this expanded messaged can also be expanded and so on.

Comment: yes yes i understood, that's why you need to have a good structure with `<div's>` or `<tr's>` , being easy for you to expand messages, like this: first message `id=MSG1`, the reply messages would be a array (tree) of that message so, you can do like `<tr id= "MSG1">` `<tr id=MSG1_REPLY1>` `<tr id= MSG1_REPLY2>` and so on, try to thing first in the structure ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think other answer is to complicated. For me it's seems like you need

```
   <div class="rowContainer">
      <div style="float:right">
         <uc:YourControl>
      </div>
   <div>
```

for row of your expandable controls.
When user will quick on expand button page will add another one of YourControls to div.rowContainer with parent another div with float right:

```
   <div class="rowContainer">
      <div style="float:right">
         <uc:YourControl>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right">
         <uc:YourControl>
      </div>
   <div>
```

When user will add another row of messages add another row container with div.rowContainer:

```
   <div class="allMessagesContainer">
      <div class="rowContainer">
         <div style="float:right">
            <uc:YourControl>
         </div>
      <div>
      <div style="clear:both">
      <div class="rowContainer">
         <div style="float:right">
            <uc:YourControl>
         </div>
      <div>
   </div>
```

`clear:both` is important since is breaking float to next line.
I think wolud be goo to create 3 controls:
1. `<uc:YourControl>` with single message
2. Control from `div.rowContainer` to easy append messages to the left, just add another one to server `div` with `float:right` inside same control.
3. Control for all messages to easy adding messages in next row. Just add another row control to container.

Also floating of controls will not force user to scroll to the left infinitely. It's not nice and they hate that.

And just one more: asp.net is not really for this kind of sites. Things get quickly complicated. What if button in one of nested controls should do something on Page? 
Should you add method to Page and cast it on control? `((MyPage)Page).DoSomeWork()`
What if type of Page change? Create interface? Maybe delegate instead. Where put him? In the Page? Control? Create event and bubble it's through all parents? Some context class?

And not mention with necessity of reinitialization of dynamic controls tree every-single-time post back is send.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 MSG
>       2 MSG  
>       Response
>       ...etc...

... you can do like this :)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to CSS, simple is better.

My suggestion, if you must have it this way in terms of layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="message"><FirstMessage /></div>
    <div class="message"><ExpandedFirstMessage /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="message"><Reply /></div>
    ...etc...
</div>
```

You create a div for each "row" or expanded responses, using a div with class "row.". Then, each message has its own div with class "message", using the following CSS:

```
.message {
    width: 200px; // or whatever size you want here
    height: 100px; // or whatever size you want here
    display: inline-block; // This is the important part!
    ...etc // your extra padding, margin, whatnot.
}
```

Inline-block allows you to avoid floats and whatnot, which should make things a lot simpler. (As a bonus, people with RTL reading order will have this work automatically for them.)

*Now, here's your problem.*

From the image you've described, it looks as though anyone can reply to any message, or expand any message; this means, logically, that the grid layout you've described might not work well. (For instance, what if someone replies to Expanded First Message, and someone else expands Reply to First Message? You would have to Message usercontrols that would be vying for the same space. How would that work?) I would suggest implementing a different design that would accommodate your usage flow, unless you have something more specific planned.

I hope this answer helps you. Good luck.